# What is the semantic of having an item flow between Blocks rather than Parts in SysML 1.4?

Tags: uml, sysml

From my understanding, SysML 1.4 allows to have itemFlows between Block as well as Part
Here is an excerpt from pag 75 of the SysML 1.4 specs
[image]

which shows that it is possible to have itemFlow(s) between Blocks.

I am not sure about the semantic of this.
For example, referring to the excerpt from the SysML 1.4 specs, does it mean that every instance of Engine block requires an "itemFlow" connection to an instance of a Transmission block and that a Torque will flow between every Instance of Engine block to the associated instance of Transmission Block?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. At least if the Engine/Transmission are blocks instantiated from this model.

You are free to define other Engines/Transmissions where not Torque is transported (e.g. if you see a copper cable as transmission where current is transported rather than torque).

An item flow in general tells that "something physical" is moved from source to target. The above transports torque. You can also transport current, gas, fluid, etc. Even abstract information can be transported, though SysML is designed to map physical objects, rather than abstract things (where UML will be sufficient).

Answer (score 0):

There is an association between `Engine` and `Transmission`. Since we don't see any multiplicity, we may assume that it is 1. That means every `Engine` instance must be linked to a `Transmission` instance and vice versa. This is not realistic, but hey, who wants models of reality ;-). In the real world the multiplicity is 0..1.

The item flow just says, that `Torque` can potentially flow across a link between the two instances.

By the way: This is also not realistic, since torque is the *potential* to flow, not the *item* flowing. The item is rather angular momentum. For reasons I don't understand, the *potential* (e.g. Torque) or the *rate* (e.g. Current) is often used in place of the item that is flowing in reality.